# how to create a custom autocomplete component in vue js?

Tags: html, vue.js

Currently i am using buefy autocomplete.But there are a few issues with it.

DepartmentDetail.vue

```
<template slot-scope="props">
  <div class="container is-fluid">
    <b-loading :is-full-page="true" :active.sync="this.isLoading"></b-loading>
<b-field label="Business Unit">
      <b-autocomplete
        :data="dataBusinessUnit"
        placeholder="select a business unit..."
        field="businessUnit"
        :loading="isFetching"
        :value="this.objectData.businessUnit"
        @typing="getAsyncDataBusinessUnit"
        @select="(option) => {updateValue(option.id,'businessUnit')}"
      >
        <template slot-scope="props">
          <div class="container">
            <p>
              <b>ID:</b>
              {{props.option.id}}
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>Description:</b>
              {{props.option.description}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </template>
        <template slot="empty">No results found</template>                
      </b-autocomplete>
    </b-field> 
</div>
</template>
```

Function that fetches the results based on user input-

```
    getAsyncDataBusinessUnit: debounce(function(name) {
     //  console.log('getAsyncDataBusinessUnit you typed'+name);
      if (!name.length) {
        this.dataBusinessUnit = [];
        return;
      }
      this.isFetching = true;
      api
        .getSearchData(this.sessionData.key,`/businessunit/${name}`)
        .then(response => {
          this.dataBusinessUnit = [];
          response.forEach(item => {
            this.dataBusinessUnit.push(item);
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.dataBusinessUnit = [];
          throw error;
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.isFetching = false;
        });
    }, 500),
```

So instead of using the buefy's b-autocomplete i want to create and use my own autocomplete component.
So i went ahead and created my own autocomplete component and called it from the DepartmentDetail vue page like this-

DepartmentDetail.vue

```
<b-field label="Custom Business Unit ">
    <AutoComplete :method="getAsyncDataBusinessUnit" title='businessUnit'   :autocompleteData="dataBusinessUnit" viewname='DepartmentDetail'>
      </AutoComplete>
</b-field>
```

AutoComplete.vue

```
<template>

  <div class="autocomplete">
    <input style="font-size: 12pt; height: 36px; width:1800px; " type="text"    v-model="this.objectData[this.title]" @input="getAsyncDataBusinessUnit"/>
<ul v-show="isFetching" >
      <li v-for="(dataBusinessUnit, i) in dataBusinessUnit" :key="i" @click="setResult(dataBusinessUnit)" >
         <!-- {{ autocompleteData }} -->
          <template v-if="title!='manager'">
          <div class="container">
            <p>
              <b>ID:</b>
              {{dataBusinessUnit.id}}
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>Description:</b>
              {{dataBusinessUnit.description}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </template>
         <template v-else>
        <div class="container">
            <p>
              <b>ID:</b>
              {{dataBusinessUnit.id}}
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>First Name:</b>
              {{dataBusinessUnit.firstName}}
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>Last Name:</b>
              {{dataBusinessUnit.lastName}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </template>
           </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import { viewMixin } from "../viewMixin.js";
import schemaData from '../store/schema';
import debounce from "lodash/debounce";
import api from "../store/api";
const ViewName = "AutoComplete";
var passedview;

export default {
  name: "AutoComplete",
   props: {
    method: { 
        type: Function 
        },
        title: String,
        viewname:String,
        autocompleteData: {
       type: Array,
       required: true
    }
  },
  

   data() {
    return {
  //   results: [],
      dataBusinessUnit: [],
      isFetching: false
     // vignesh: this.objectData[this.title]
    };
  }, 
  computed: {
            viewData() {
                return this.$store.getters.getViewData('DepartmentDetail')
            },
            objectData() {             
                  return this.$store.getters.getApiData(this.viewData.api_id).data
            },
            sessionData() {
                return this.$store.getters.getSessionData()
            },
            isLoading() {
                return this.$store.getters.getApiData(this.viewData.api_id).isLoading
            },
            newRecord() {
                return this.$route.params.id === null;
            },
            getTitle() {
              return this.title
            }            
  }, 
    mounted() {
     
      
  },
    methods: {
       setResult(result) {
      
          this.updateValue(result.id,this.title);
        //  localStorage.setItem(this.title,result.id );        
         this.isFetching = false;
      },  
        updateValue(newValue, fieldName) {
                var val;

                var schema = schemaData[this.viewData.schema];
               

                if(typeof schema!=='undefined' && schema['properties'][fieldName]['type'] == 'date'){
                    val = this.formatDate(newValue);
                } else {
                    val = newValue;
                }
                
                this.$store.dispatch('updateDataObjectField', {
                    key: this.viewData.api_id,
                    field: fieldName,
                    value: val
                });
            },
            
 getAsyncDataBusinessUnit: debounce(function(name) {
             
       console.log('getAsyncDataBusinessUnit you typed'+name.target.value);
      if (!name.target.value.length) {
        this.dataBusinessUnit = [];
        this.isFetching = false;
        return;
      }
   //   this.isFetching = true;
      

      api
        .getSearchData(this.sessionData.key,`/businessunit/${name.target.value}`)
        .then(response => {
          this.dataBusinessUnit = [];
          if (!response.length)
          {
            console.log('inside if')
          this.isFetching = false;
          }

          else{
            console.log('inside else')
            response.forEach(item => {
            this.dataBusinessUnit.push(item);
          });
          this.isFetching = true;
          }
         
          console.log('length of dataBusinessUnit is '+(this.dataBusinessUnit).length)
          console.log('contents of dataBusinessUnit array '+JSON.stringify(this.dataBusinessUnit))
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.dataBusinessUnit = [];
          throw error;
        })
        .finally(() => {
         // this.isFetching = true;
        });

    }, 500), 
      
    },
    
    components: {
    

    }

};
</script>
```

The issue iam facing is whenever i start to type anything into the Custom Business Unit input field, then immediately after 1-2 seconds the value gets reset(with the value coming from the store getters ).This however does not happen if i remove the line this.dataBusinessUnit = []; in the getAsyncDataBusinessUnit function . Why is this happening? I even tried using :input instead of v-model for the input field , but i am still facing the same issue.And also second issue is when i click an existing record under DepartmentDetail page, the value that should be set  for the custom business unit input field coming from the store getters (this.objectData.businessUnit) is not showing up sometimes? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic logic of an autocomplete is not really hard:

```js
Vue.component('Autocomplete', {
  props: ['list'],
  data() {
    return {
      input: null
    }
  },
  template: `<div><input v-model="input" @input="handleInput"><div class="bordered" v-if="input"><ul><li v-for="(item, i) in list" :key="i" @click="setInput(item)">{{ item }}</li></ul></div></div>`,
  methods: {
    handleInput(e) {
      this.$emit('input', e.target.value)
    },
    setInput(value) {
      this.input = value
      this.$emit('input', value)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    filteredList() {
      if (this.filterInput) {
        return this.list.filter(e => e.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filterInput.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
      } else {
        return this.list
      }
    }
  },
  data: {
    filterInput: null,
    list: [
      "First",
      "Second",
      "Third",
      "Fourth",
      "Fifth",
      "Sixth",
      "Seventh"
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput(e) {
      this.filterInput = e
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.bordered {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <autocomplete :list="filteredList" @input="handleInput" />
</div>
```

I wouldn't handle the data in the presentational component (`autocomplete` is a presentational component in the structure I created), but in its parent-container. That way the `autocomplete` just gets a list as a prop and displays it; every action is `$emit`ted to the parent, who does the data-handling.

It's easier to control displayed data this way - even with an `async` data source.

Comment: ok so even the values coming from the  store getters (this.objectData.buisnessunit) should be passed as a prop from the parent compoent to the child compoent(autocomplete.vue) when it is called?

Comment: @VigneshSwaminathan I would do that - the presentational component is not concerned with the data (e.g. where it comes from), only displays it. The container component solves all the data handling part, and actually (in the simplified case of my snippet) its only purpose is to prepare (and update) the list that it passes to the child. You can read more about this structure if you search Google with the **"vue container presentational"** keywords.

Comment: <b-field label="Custom Business Unit ">
    <AutoComplete :value="this.objectData.buisnessunit"          :method="getAsyncDataBusinessUnit" title='businessUnit'   :autocompleteData="dataBusinessUnit" viewname='DepartmentDetail'>
      </AutoComplete>
</b-field>

Comment: :value="this.objectData.buisnessunit" <---- this is how to pass the store getter value as  prop to the child component(autocomplete.vue) ?

Comment: and in the child component once this prop value is recieved i  should just assign the prop value to the v-model in the autocomplete vue?

Comment: @VigneshSwaminathan you should think about the structure of your components: `autocomplete` should be only there to PRESENT the data (the autocomplete list, the input value, etc.) and send back everything to parent for evaluation, while the parent (container) should be there to HANDLE the data (to refresh & pass it down for presentation). And actually I see an error in your code: `v-model="this.objectData[this.title]"` should be `v-model="objectData[title]"` (no `this` before `objectData` and `title`) - in the template `props`, `data` & `computed` are proxied, so you don't need `this`.

Comment: thank you so much.i removed the 'this' keyword before objectData and title and the resetting issue is not happening anymore

Comment: only issue is the value of the field is not comming up on page load. But if start typing (@input) then suddenly the value shows up in the textbox

Comment: i will try the $emit approach

Comment: and also how do i close the dropdown when clicked on any outside area?

Comment: @VigneshSwaminathan closing the dropdown is bit other topic - I’ll try to update the snippet with that when I have the spare time